# Python pip failure to install constraint module

Tags: python

I tried to install the constraint module with `pip3 install constraint` but it gave me this error message

```
Collecting constraint
  Using cached constraint-0.4.1.tar.gz (48 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/hh/42wbm77x3z985755445kshw80000gn/T/pip-install-p1hsufh7/constraint/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/hh/42wbm77x3z985755445kshw80000gn/T/pip-install-p1hsufh7/constraint/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/hh/42wbm77x3z985755445kshw80000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-jc6g6vwi
         cwd: /private/var/folders/hh/42wbm77x3z985755445kshw80000gn/T/pip-install-p1hsufh7/constraint/
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/hh/42wbm77x3z985755445kshw80000gn/T/pip-install-p1hsufh7/constraint/setup.py", line 143
        except OSError, ex:
                      ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: Is that a 10 year old project with no updates to it?
https://pypi.org/project/constraint/#description

Answer (score 6):

Try the command `pip install python-constraint`.

Answer (score 2):

---

The situation is like this:

```
try:
    print(int('hello'))

except ValueError, ex:
    print('Opps!')
```

Output:

```
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/text.py", line 4
    except ValueError, ex:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

**You need to change the comma to `as`:**

```
try:
    print(int('hello'))

except ValueError as ex:
    print('Opps!')
```

Output:

```
Opps!
```

---

*The reason this happens is because that package was made for python 2, and in python 2, the error handler uses a `,` unlike python 3, that uses `as`.*

---